# Kill process.exec function

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I have a function to execute a process:

```
static async runTest() { await process.exec(`start ${currentDir}/forward.py`); }

runTest();
```

The python script will continue to run until it's killed, which I don't know how to do at the moment. So in short, I want to kill this process manually at some point. How I would I do this? Thank you!

Comment: The python script is intentionally running until kill. It's just a keypress action that holds down a key. I just need it to hold down this key for as long as the script is running, and then when it's killed it will stop. Hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exec return value is a child-process object and you can kill it anytime by calling the .kill() function. For more info, you can refer to this

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

I demonstrated the kill function using a simple timeout.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
    
    let childprocess = exec('python a.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
    
        if (stderr) {
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
    
        console.log(`stdout:\n${stdout}`);
    });
    
    setTimeout(() => {  //Example killing
        childprocess.kill() 
    }, 2000);
```